# Como preencher todo um vetor com malloc(sizeof(int)) com algum valor

Tags: c, array, malloc

Estou com um problema, não tenho ideia de como preencher este vetor com algum valor, por exemplo, eu quero preencher ele todo com -1 (iniciar ele todo com -1).
O problema aqui é que eu não sei exatamente qual o tamanho do meu vetor.

```
    typedef struct argumentosThread {   
        int dim, queens, posicoes, total;
        int *posicCertas;               
        int head;                       
    }ArgumentosThread;
```

La no meio do codigo eu inicializo ele, eu coloquei o sizeof(int) porque eu não sei qual vai ser o tamanho do vetor, ele pode ser bem pequeno ou então MUITO grande.

```
    argumentos->posicCertas = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Tem que saber de alguma forma, não existe milagre. O que fez não é criar um vetor, está criando um único elemento, neste caso você sabe o tamanho, é 1.

Comment: Qual vetor ? Se está a falar do `argumentos->posicCertas` ele é iniciado como um ponteiro para um inteiro apenas e  não um vetor propriamente dito

Answer (score 1):

No momento em que alocar esse vetor usando malloc, armazene também seu tamanho na estrutura...

E faça um laço for para preencher conforme deseje.

```
argumentos->posicCertas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n_pos);
argumentos->n_pos = n_pos;
```

Depois só fazer um for preenchendo o vetor.

É interessante também fazer um casting do retorno do malloc.